# Is it possible to use PHP with Mapserver?

Tags: php, apache, cgi, mapserver

I am using Apache and Mapserver, for creating a GIS based web application. Mapserver use CGI script. But for some specific purposes I want to use PHP, is it possible to use ? What changes I have to make in Apache's and Mapserver's configuration files?

FYI, Mapserver is an Open Source geographic data rendering engine written in C. Beyond browsing GIS data, MapServer allows you create “geographic image maps”, that is, maps that can direct users to content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Google: php mapscript, you can access many/most of the mapserver internals using PHP or other language wrappers. There is probably a good tutorial listed that will get you started.